# where should be the dropdown placed when its selections reflects the change in heading?

Tags: layout

[image]

Please have a look at the screen shot attached for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

### I'd suggest not having the duration in the title

And a slight adjustment to the dropdowns and the "Download" button should do the trick. Refer to the screenshot below.

[image: layout updated]

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with all of the changes you've made here but I *do* agree with generalising the title - The title of a page shouldn't change. Find something that covers everything the page is capable of showing.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Hope this helps]

Replaced part of header with dropdown. Hope this solves your problem.
Additional filters can be placed. You can design this better by removing the dropdown borders.